# Viewing arabic characters in R

Tags: python, r, facebook, facebook-graph-api, rstudio-server

I have extracted arabic posts from facebook with Rfacebook package in R but it was a **problem with the arabic characters** in the dataset extracted. This is example of characters showed : .

Any suggestions please?

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25654921/arabic-text-mining-using-r and see if it helps

Comment: Try to read your data in UTF8 format, check the answer of this question: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22876746/how-to-read-data-in-utf-8-format-in-r